# Spring Cloud GCP Starter Authentication Issues

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

I am using spring-cloud-gcp-starter,spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub,spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore for the autoconfiguration of my gcp dependencies.
It fetches the key from system variable:: spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key
which I am setting in my configuration class as System.setProperty("spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key","privatevalue");

There is a case where my key will be rotated every x days and I want to ensure that my application gives me authorization when the key rotates.
One way I have thought is to overwrite the system variable when my key rotates but how do we make sure gcp uses the latest key for authentication or will this approach work?.

I looked at the CredentialsProvider class and it seems they only have getter method and setter is handled via autoconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `CredentialsProvider` bean in spring-cloud-gcp is created in autoconfiguration.

In Spring Cloud ecosystem, you can refresh configuration by using `@RefreshScope`. So then all configurations in this scope will get refreshed when the `/refresh` endpoint is hit. Read more in spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#refresh-scope).

For rotating the keys, you can override the `CredentialsProvider` bean in your configuration with `@RefreshScope`, so that you can refresh your keys without restarting the application.

You can refer to how it is done in [this sample application](https://github.com/elefeint/examples/blob/main/pubsub-rotate-credentials/src/main/java/com/example/CredentialRefreshConfig.java#L25-L39).